# Selenium webdriver Chrome dont detect all the checkbox and dropdown menu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I`m creating project in selenium for site: amazon.com. I have problem with changing language. Selenium doesn`t detect all the elements during page loading: check boxes and drop-down menus.

[1.After loading site by script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JDbH8.png)

[2.After loading site manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LVug4.png)

I dont see all the language and currency menu (red box with 2 screenshot)
I tried with custom profile in Chrome and with Firefox but it didnt work:

```
    def setUp(self):
        options = Options() 
        options.add_argument("--profile-directory=Default")
        options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=selenium")
        options.add_argument('start-maximized')  
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

The url when selenium run is:https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-preferences/select-language?preferencesReturnUrl=%2F

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url = 'https://www.amazon.com/gp/customer-preferences/select-language?preferencesReturnUrl=%2F'

driver.get(url)

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="a-button-inner" and contains(string(),"Cancel")]').click()
driver.get(url)
```

That options comes up only if you first cancels the first prompt and open it again